# Dojo DataGrid export to excel

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

I have used exporter plugin the datagrid and have got the grid data in CSV format.
But I want to make this data to be downloadable in excel format. One solution is that I can send an ajax request to server and send back the excel.

Just wanted to know if there is a way by which this excel can be created and downloaded without hitting server.

My export code as of now is:

```
        function exportAll(){
            dijit.byId("grid").exportGrid("csv", function(str){
                alert('Data to be exported',str);
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See

[Exporting a dojo datagrid to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440803/exporting-a-dojo-datagrid-to-a-csv-file)

You cannot open excel via javascript so it needs to be a GET download request.

Send the `str` to server with `xhrPost`, put into temp-file there, print the temp-url and in the `xhrPost` success callback function, call `window.open("./" + responseText, "_new");`. Its also possible to use the `io.iframe` transport one of the answers in that post shows.

```
   function exportAll(){
        dijit.byId("grid").exportGrid("csv", function(str){
            dojo.xhrPost({
                url: '/putExportData.php',
                load: function(tempUrl) {
                    window.open(tempUrl, "_new");
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: I think it is more of limitation/security of JavaScript than Dojo having any issues.

Comment: it is.. You could get into ActiveX component if you'd want to support this in IE. It has the capeability to write to disk - whereas JS is denied this feature (except for session/cookie storage ofc)